# Should i get a new companion for my rat or? (Graphic)

Tags: behavior, bonding, rodents

So i got 3 bonded pet rats, over the past week, 2 of the three killed and ate the smallest rat, (i had thought he escaped for 4 days)(iv had them for 7 months) who had trouble putting on weight  (fed separately) but lived in cage with them, however last night the last 2 rats turnd on eachother and one killed the other and started to eat the other before i woke up and was like WTF? anyways, the last rat, wich killed 2 of its companions and ate them. (Note that there was food in the cage when they did so) should i put him down or try bonding him to a new rat in hope ot gose well

Comment: What are you usually feeding them and have they recently been checked by a vet? Aside from dysfunctional behavior, malnutrition could explain the trouble putting on weight and the other rats eating their companion.